# Canvas Layers Order Issue using IText and Text #FabricJS

Tags: canvas, text, itext, fabricjs

I am using an array to store Canvas elements and we iterate the array however when we push this to the canvas IText and Text goes to the bottom layer in the Canvas.
Does anyone know a solution for this or have you run into a similar issue in the past? I used `fabric.js 4.3.1` version. Thank you

Comment: Can you give your sample code?

Comment: Doesn't anything other than Text and IText go to the bottom? Also can you give your sample code?